# Perl - replacing sequences of identical characters

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to implement a regexp that, given a string, it checks for a sequence of at least 3 of identical characters and replaces it with two of that character. For example, I want to turn the below string:

```
sstttttrrrrrrriing
```

into

```
ssttrriing
```

I am thinking of something along the lines of...

```
$string =~ s/(\D{3,})/substr($1, 0, 2)/e;
```

But this will not work because:

1. It doesn't check if the three alphabetical characters are identical; it can match a sequence of three or more **distinct** characters.
2. It only replaces the first match; I need to accommodate for all matches in this regexp.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a capture group and backreference it with `\1`, then insert it twice afterwards.

```
$ perl -plwe 's/(.)\1{2,}/$1$1/g'
sstttttrrrrrrriing
ssttrriing
```

Or you can use the `\K` (keep) escape sequence to avoid having to re-insert.

```
s/(.)\1\K\1+//g
```

Replace wildcard `.` for any suitable character (class) if needed. For example for letters:

```
perl -plwe 's/(\pL)\1\K\1+//g'
```

Comment: The back-referencing is just what I'm looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
$ echo "sssssttttttrrrrriiiinnnnggg" | perl -pe "s/(.)\1+/\1\1/g"
ssttrriinngg
```